# How Do I Fill In The Gaps Between The Chapters

Tags: novel, technique, structure, brainstorming

I know this may come off as weird or strange but i want to know how do i finish my novel. The thing is that i already know how to end it and i have a impeccable beginning but that isn't how a novel works. I need to know how should fill up novel by connecting the dots in orderly fashion without rushing or dragging the novel. 
Thank You In Advance

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. This is a very broad question as asked. If you search under the tag `plot` you will find many suggestions and resources which may be able to help you.

Comment: Please consider editing your question to narrow it down, as per Lauren't suggestion. We'll edit the answers if needed, too.

Answer (score 3):

It is time for the dreaded lists. Lists are a valuable tool in building a complicated project. Specifically I would make lists of unresolved plot points already in the narrative, plot points to be put in the narrative, order of events, and minor characters. The minor characters does not directly help your situation, but I find it very helpful (assuming you don't also have a list of major characters). After you have prepared your lists (in pencil, not ink, as these will change as you work) start with the order of events, and look at what happens next. Is it interesting? Can it be skipped? Would it help resolve an unresolved plot point? can it be used to introduce another plot point? If you decide not to skip it pick one to three plot points that may work well with that event and write the scene. Update your lists by marking off events that are documented, plot points that have been introduced, and unresolved plot points that are now resolved. Add any unresolved plot points that are new and new minor characters to the respective lists. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 1):

With the middle of a book, the best considered method is small rises of tension followed by a slight drop (to allow your reader to recover).

To use a driving analogy, the beginning of your book is getting in the car and starting the engine, the end is arriving at your destination but it's the middle part that's actually the journey.  It could be a simple journey with no dramas but it could be filled with problems that need to be overcome (a flat tyre that needs changing, running out of fuel, narrowly missing an animal that runs in front of the car).  Each could be considered a potential end to the journey but the hero must and will overcome each problem and continue to the end.

Each problem must be realistic and usually, the hero should solve them his/herself though with help when it is available.  A kind stranger could stop to help change the tyre or give a lift to the nearest garage for fuel for example.  Or perhaps your hero is very untrustworthy and doesn't want to the help.

I can't post pictures but if you Google 3 act story arc, you'll see examples of the rise up, small fall method.

Answer (score 0):

The Elements of Fiction Writing series, published by Writers Digest Books, has some great books to help with this.

Those that would apply here are:
Plot
Beginnings, Middles, & Ends
Scene & Structure

Answer (score 0):

The start and the end are mere bookends to the body of the story. The body of the story is where characters develop and plot and events unfold.

That said a good start can hook a read and a good end can leave them satisfied and wanting more.

So assuming that you find the opening and the close where your creativity is strongest go with that. Plan the journey (be that plot, character or otherwise) into episodes. Then write the opener and the close of an episode. Then tell the pertinent story that relates to the growth of the character and the key events of that episode. Include any details that will matter in future episodes.

Before you know it you will have a series of chapters with each one resulting from the events of the one before. Characters reacting to what happened and then reacting to the results of their reaction and before you know it you will have a well paced story of things that start and things that end and things that continue from one episode to the next.

The chances are that your chapters will be well paced and keep the reader hooked. Your endings need only make them want to read the next chapter and the opening of that chapter need only make them want to read the whole chapter.

The chances are that your first draft will not be perfect. that's okay, don't worry about it. You can fix that later.

It is quite likely that there will be sense that are uninteresting, slow and not needed for the story - you can always remove them later just write them for now.

Tell the story and then fix the other issues later.